# MySQL Insert trigger not working: Count not matched

Tags: mysql

Creating a trigger is not working as expected, whenever I try to insert data into master table it give me error that count does't match. I am unable to identify where I'm doing wrong.

I have attached error image please look for further demonstration

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER  IF EXISTS  `trg_apl_b_info_after_insert`

CREATE
    TRIGGER `trg_apl_b_info_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_appli_basic_info` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   DECLARE vApplicant VARCHAR(256);

   -- Find appli_basic_info_id & apli_reg_no of Applicant performing the INSERT into table
   SELECT USER() INTO vApplicant;

   -- Insert record into tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert table
   INSERT INTO tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert
   ( appli_basic_info_id,
     apli_reg_no,
     full_name,
     after_insert_datetime)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.appli_basic_info_id,
     NEW.apli_reg_no,
     NEW.full_name,
     SYSDATE(),
     vApplicant );

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

[Error in phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ96Dl.jpg)

Comment: I checked the code again now i set the column accordingly but still giving error.                              
 CREATE TRIGGER trg_appli_basic_info_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON tbl_appli_basic_info FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  -- Insert record into tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert table
   INSERT INTO tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert
   ( appli_basic_info_id,
     apli_reg_no,
     full_name,
     after_insert_datetime)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.appli_basic_info_id,
     NEW.apli_reg_no,
     NEW.full_name,
     SYSDATE()
     );

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statement lists 4 fields however you provided 5 values. Hence count not matched.